# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (functionjs.js)

Tags: javascript, range, callstack, stack-memory

I'm trying to build a recruitment management website (nodejs), but when I'm almost done I get this error:
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. functionjs.js`

Here is my functionjs.js source code:

```
export const funLine = () => {
    var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

    var tabActive = $(".item.active");
    var line = $(".line_slide");

    if (line && tabActive) {
        line.style.left = tabActive.offsetLeft + "px";
        line.style.width = tabActive.offsetWidth + "px";
    }
};
export const lineSlide = () => {
    var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
    var $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
    var line = $(".line_slide");
    if (line) {
        var tabItem = $$(".item");
        tabItem.forEach((tab, index) => {
            tab.onclick = function () {
                $(".item.active")?.classList?.remove("active");
                line.style.width = this.offsetWidth + "px";
                line.style.left = this.offsetLeft + "px";
                this.classList.add("active");
            };
        });
    }
};
export const checkBar = (bar_ref, nav_ref, line_ref) => {
    var widthScreen = window.innerWidth;
    const bar = bar_ref;
    const nav = nav_ref;
    const line = line_ref;
    if (bar && nav && line) {
        if (widthScreen <= 800) {
            nav.classList.add("menu--hident");
            bar.style.display = "flex";
            line.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            nav.classList.remove("menu--hident");
            bar.style.display = "none";
            line.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
};
export const openMenu = (bar_ref) => {
    const bar = bar_ref;
    if (bar) {
        const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
        bar.onclick = () => {
            if ($(".bar.menu__bar")) {
                $(".bar.menu__bar").classList.remove("menu__bar");
                $(".bar").classList.add("menu__barClose");
                $(".menu--hident").style.right = "-16px";
                // $(".menu--hident").style.opacity = "1";
            } else {
                $(".bar.menu__barClose").classList.remove("menu__barClose");
                $(".bar").classList.add("menu__bar");
                $(".menu--hident").style.right = "100%";
                // $(".menu--hident").style.opacity = "0";
            }
        };
    }
};
export const checkDate = (e) => {
    if (e) {
        // var ngay = e.substr(8, 2);
        var thang = e.substr(5, 2);
        var nam = e.substr(0, 4);
        return "Tháng " + thang + ", " + nam;
    }
};
export const checkDateCompany = (e) => {
    if (e) {
        // var ngay = e.substr(8, 2);
        var thang = e.substr(5, 2);
        var nam = e.substr(0, 4);
        return "Tháng " + thang + "/" + nam;
    }
};
export const formatDateWork = (e) => {
    if (e) {
        var ngay = e.substr(8, 2);
        var thang = e.substr(5, 2);
        var nam = e.substr(0, 4);
        return ngay + "/" + thang + "/" + nam;
    }
};
export const checkDateDealtime = (e) => {
    if (e) {
        const today = new Date();
        if (new Date(e) > today) {
            return "Chưa hết hạn";
        } else {
            return "Đã hết hạn";
        }
    }
};
export const checkArrayEquar = (a, b) => {
    if (a.length !== b.length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
export const checkStatus = (e) => {
    if (e) {
        let data = [];
        let a = e.rows;
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].status === 0) {
                data.push(a[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
};
export const GetCategoryHome = (e) => {
    let list = e.rows;
    if (list.length !== 0) {
        let data = [];
        let result = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            data.push({
                id: list[i].id,
                name: list[i].name,
                icon: list[i].icon,
                length: list[i]?.Works?.length,
            });
        }
        data.sort((a, b) => {
            return b.length - a.length;
        });
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (result.length < 8) {
                result.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
export const FormatProvince = (e) => {
    if (e) {
        if (e.search("Thành phố") !== -1) {
            return e.substr(10);
        } else {
            return e.substr(5);
        }
    }
};
export const getQueryVariable = (variable) => {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] === variable) {
            return pair[1].split("%20").join(" ");
        }
    }
    return false;
};
export const removeVietnameseTones = (str) => {
    str = str.replace(/à|á|ạ|ả|ã|â|ầ|ấ|ậ|ẩ|ẫ|ă|ằ|ắ|ặ|ẳ|ẵ/g, "a");
    str = str.replace(/è|é|ẹ|ẻ|ẽ|ê|ề|ế|ệ|ể|ễ/g, "e");
    str = str.replace(/ì|í|ị|ỉ|ĩ/g, "i");
    str = str.replace(/ò|ó|ọ|ỏ|õ|ô|ồ|ố|ộ|ổ|ỗ|ơ|ờ|ớ|ợ|ở|ỡ/g, "o");
    str = str.replace(/ù|ú|ụ|ủ|ũ|ư|ừ|ứ|ự|ử|ữ/g, "u");
    str = str.replace(/ỳ|ý|ỵ|ỷ|ỹ/g, "y");
    str = str.replace(/đ/g, "d");
    str = str.replace(/À|Á|Ạ|Ả|Ã|Â|Ầ|Ấ|Ậ|Ẩ|Ẫ|Ă|Ằ|Ắ|Ặ|Ẳ|Ẵ/g, "A");
    str = str.replace(/È|É|Ẹ|Ẻ|Ẽ|Ê|Ề|Ế|Ệ|Ể|Ễ/g, "E");
    str = str.replace(/Ì|Í|Ị|Ỉ|Ĩ/g, "I");
    str = str.replace(/Ò|Ó|Ọ|Ỏ|Õ|Ô|Ồ|Ố|Ộ|Ổ|Ỗ|Ơ|Ờ|Ớ|Ợ|Ở|Ỡ/g, "O");
    str = str.replace(/Ù|Ú|Ụ|Ủ|Ũ|Ư|Ừ|Ứ|Ự|Ử|Ữ/g, "U");
    str = str.replace(/Ỳ|Ý|Ỵ|Ỷ|Ỹ/g, "Y");
    str = str.replace(/Đ/g, "D");
    str = str.replace(/\u0300|\u0301|\u0303|\u0309|\u0323/g, ""); // ̀ ́ ̃ ̉ ̣  huyền, sắc, ngã, hỏi, nặng
    str = str.replace(/\u02C6|\u0306|\u031B/g, ""); // ˆ ̆ ̛  Â, Ê, Ă, Ơ, Ư
    str = str.replace(/ + /g, " ");
    str = str.trim();
};
```

"The function causing the "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error is the checkStatus function. This function calls itself recursively, which means that it keeps calling itself over and over again until the call stack overflows. This can happen if the e parameter is not an array or if the array contains objects with circular references." Is that right?

To fix this bug, I tried to fix it by adding a base case to some function. But it doesn't work:((
Is there any way to resolve this?
Please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Max call stack error means that there is a function that calls itself, and there is either no condition for it to *not* call itself, or this condition is never satisfied.

Comment: I got it, thank a lot! but when t did it I have a new problem.  " Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/client'
    at webpackMissingModule (index.js:25:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-native-web/dist/exports/render/index.js (index.js:25:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)

Comment: at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-native-web/dist/index.js (index.js:36:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-native-render-html/lib/commonjs/TRenderEngineProvider.js (TRenderEngineProvider.tsx:3:1)"

Comment: What should I do?